# How to get rid of uppercase in header lines?

Tags: header-footer, uppercase

my document class is  "book" and the chapter and section titles show in uppercase in the header line. How can i have it in lowercase? I am attaching a pic for clarifying. I also would like "Chapter 2" in the pic appear as "2".

[image: first]

Edit: I want my header look like this pic:

[image: second]

Here, 5 refers to chapter 5 and Hints refers to the chapter name.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just to clarify: Do you wish to render the header line truly in all-lowercase, i.e., as "generating functions and powerful identitities"? Or should the header line be rendered the way the string is given in the argument of `\chapter`?

Comment: @Mico Initially I too thought the same, but after that I realized that the `OP` wants to change only `CHAPTER 2` to `Chapter 2`, hope I'm correct...

Comment: @MadyYuvi - Thanks. Let's see if the OP will reply and clarify what he/she wants.

Comment: Please also clarify what you would like section-related header lines to look like. E.g., if there's a command called `\section{Preliminaries}`, should the header line say "preliminaries", "Preliminaries", or "PRELIMINARIES" (the default)? And, should the header line continue to be rendered in *slanted* font shape?

Comment: Thank you @Mico and MandyYuvi . I want "CHAPTER 2. GENERATING..." appear as "2 Generting Functions and..." just like how its written in the chapters. In springer book, the headline does show "Chaper 2" . its shows only 2  which refers to the chapter number. Thanks again

Comment: @Mico I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have interpreted your objectives as follows:

- Don't render chapter-level and section-level header strings in UPPERCASE
- Strip out the "Chapter" prefix string and remove the "dot" after the chapter number and the section number
- Don't typeset the chapter and section header strings in a *slanted* font shape.

In the `book` document class, the low-level macro `\ps@headings` governs how the header lines are constructed. To achieve your objectives, it's necessary to modify this macro as follows (insert the code in the preamble):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\patchcmd' macro
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{\thechapter\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\thesection. \ }{\thesection\ }{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\slshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings} % re-load the modified code of `\ps@headings`
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up questions: In order to make the header information generated by the `\tableofcontents`, `\listoftables`, and `\listoffigures` commands and by the `thebibliography` and `theindex` environments without the action of `\MakeUppercase`, you also need to run the following five instructions *twice*:

```
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
```

Comment: Using `\patchcmd` is awesome technique...Great and effective suggestion....

Comment: its working perfect i just copy-pasted it. You even gave it all ready. Thanks infinity.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I just found out about it. Thanks for your interest in the question . I am sure i will learn a lot from you guys.

Comment: Sorry to bother. I see that only "CONTENTS" is upper cased. Is it fixable?.

Comment: @AliShather Can you provide a simple example regarding `CONTENTS`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I mean all chapters and sections show in lowercase but CONTENTS shows in uppercase.

Comment: @AliShather - To get rid of the uppercasing of the "Contents" string in the header line in the table of contents portion of the document, you should run `\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}`*twice*. Ditto if your document has `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` commands.

Comment: @Mico all is perfect now. You the best. Hats off.

Comment: Hi Mico, i have a question if you dont mind. Bibliography is still in uppercase. i tried `\patchcmd{\bibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}` and it didnt work.

Comment: Sure I will post

Comment: @AliShather - You were very close. You need to run `\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}`, *twice*.

Comment: @AliShather - I've gone ahead and posted the gist of the preceding comments in an addendum to the answer. That way, the information will hopefully be seen by more future readers of this posting.

Comment: I cant thank you enough Mico ..God bless you. Actually I tried what you said before i ask the question but it didnt work because I wrote `\bibliography` instead of `\thebibliography`. Its all perfect now. I have more questions regarding other issues. I will post in future. Thanks again Mico.